# Django Two Factor Authentication - Remove Token Generator Option From Wizard

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I've been playing with Django Two Factor authentication for the last two days or so, and I have it partially working.  I am trying to figure out a way to remove the QR Token Generator.  I have tried subclassing the setup view, but the form wizard is causing me some grief.  The wizard is confusing me.  I know in a regular form, how to remove radio buttons, but in this case, I can't seem to locate the source of the Token Generator.

The SetupView...

```
@class_view_decorator(never_cache)
@class_view_decorator(login_required)
class SetupView(IdempotentSessionWizardView):
    """
    View for handling OTP setup using a wizard.
    The first step of the wizard shows an introduction text, explaining how OTP
    works and why it should be enabled. The user has to select the verification
    method (generator / call / sms) in the second step. Depending on the method
    selected, the third step configures the device. For the generator method, a
    QR code is shown which can be scanned using a mobile phone app and the user
    is asked to provide a generated token. For call and sms methods, the user
    provides the phone number which is then validated in the final step.
    """
    success_url = 'two_factor:setup_complete'
    qrcode_url = 'two_factor:qr'
    template_name = 'two_factor/core/setup.html'
    session_key_name = 'django_two_factor-qr_secret_key'
    initial_dict = {}
    form_list = (
        ('welcome', Form),
        ('method', MethodForm),
        ('generator', TOTPDeviceForm),
        ('sms', PhoneNumberForm),
        ('call', PhoneNumberForm),
        ('validation', DeviceValidationForm),
        ('yubikey', YubiKeyDeviceForm),
    )
    condition_dict = {
        'generator': lambda self: self.get_method() == 'generator',
        'call': lambda self: self.get_method() == 'call',
        'sms': lambda self: self.get_method() == 'sms',
        'validation': lambda self: self.get_method() in ('sms', 'call'),
        'yubikey': lambda self: self.get_method() == 'yubikey',
    }
    idempotent_dict = {
        'yubikey': False,
    }

    def get_method(self):
        method_data = self.storage.validated_step_data.get('method', {})
        return method_data.get('method', None)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Start the setup wizard. Redirect if already enabled.
        """
        if default_device(self.request.user):
            return redirect(self.success_url)
        return super(SetupView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_list(self):
        """
        Check if there is only one method, then skip the MethodForm from form_list
        """
        form_list = super(SetupView, self).get_form_list()
        available_methods = get_available_methods()
        if len(available_methods) == 1:
            form_list.pop('method', None)
            method_key, _ = available_methods[0]
            self.storage.validated_step_data['method'] = {'method': method_key}
        return form_list

    def render_next_step(self, form, **kwargs):
        """
        In the validation step, ask the device to generate a challenge.
        """
        next_step = self.steps.next
        if next_step == 'validation':
            try:
                self.get_device().generate_challenge()
                kwargs["challenge_succeeded"] = True
            except Exception:
                logger.exception("Could not generate challenge")
                kwargs["challenge_succeeded"] = False
        return super(SetupView, self).render_next_step(form, **kwargs)

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        """
        Finish the wizard. Save all forms and redirect.
        """
        # Remove secret key used for QR code generation
        try:
            del self.request.session[self.session_key_name]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        # TOTPDeviceForm
        if self.get_method() == 'generator':
            form = [form for form in form_list if isinstance(form, TOTPDeviceForm)][0]
            device = form.save()

        # PhoneNumberForm / YubiKeyDeviceForm
        elif self.get_method() in ('call', 'sms', 'yubikey'):
            device = self.get_device()
            device.save()

        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("Unknown method '%s'" % self.get_method())

        django_otp.login(self.request, device)
        return redirect(self.success_url)

    def get_form_kwargs(self, step=None):
        kwargs = {}
        if step == 'generator':
            kwargs.update({
                'key': self.get_key(step),
                'user': self.request.user,
            })
        if step in ('validation', 'yubikey'):
            kwargs.update({
                'device': self.get_device()
            })
        metadata = self.get_form_metadata(step)
        if metadata:
            kwargs.update({
                'metadata': metadata,
            })
        return kwargs

    def get_device(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Uses the data from the setup step and generated key to recreate device.
        Only used for call / sms -- generator uses other procedure.
        """
        method = self.get_method()
        kwargs = kwargs or {}
        kwargs['name'] = 'default'
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user

        if method in ('call', 'sms'):
            kwargs['method'] = method
            kwargs['number'] = self.storage.validated_step_data\
                .get(method, {}).get('number')
            return PhoneDevice(key=self.get_key(method), **kwargs)

        if method == 'yubikey':
            kwargs['public_id'] = self.storage.validated_step_data\
                .get('yubikey', {}).get('token', '')[:-32]
            try:
                kwargs['service'] = ValidationService.objects.get(name='default')
            except ValidationService.DoesNotExist:
                raise KeyError("No ValidationService found with name 'default'")
            except ValidationService.MultipleObjectsReturned:
                raise KeyError("Multiple ValidationService found with name 'default'")
            return RemoteYubikeyDevice(**kwargs)

    def get_key(self, step):
        self.storage.extra_data.setdefault('keys', {})
        if step in self.storage.extra_data['keys']:
            return self.storage.extra_data['keys'].get(step)
        key = random_hex(20).decode('ascii')
        self.storage.extra_data['keys'][step] = key
        return key

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SetupView, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)
        if self.steps.current == 'generator':
            key = self.get_key('generator')
            rawkey = unhexlify(key.encode('ascii'))
            b32key = b32encode(rawkey).decode('utf-8')
            self.request.session[self.session_key_name] = b32key
            context.update({
                'QR_URL': reverse(self.qrcode_url)
            })
        elif self.steps.current == 'validation':
            context['device'] = self.get_device()
        context['cancel_url'] = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
        return context

    def process_step(self, form):
        if hasattr(form, 'metadata'):
            self.storage.extra_data.setdefault('forms', {})
            self.storage.extra_data['forms'][self.steps.current] = form.metadata
        return super(SetupView, self).process_step(form)

    def get_form_metadata(self, step):
        self.storage.extra_data.setdefault('forms', {})
        return self.storage.extra_data['forms'].get(step, None)
```

Seems to reference a MethodForm...

```
class MethodForm(forms.Form):
    method = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Method"),
                               initial='generator',
                               widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MethodForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fields['method'].choices = get_available_methods()
```

I can't seem to track back to where the list of choices is defined, clearly in this case it is saying generator is the initial choice in setup, but I can't figure out how to remove the generator option as a list of valid choices. I also tried to remove generator from the form_list but this didn't seem to make a difference either.

If there's an easier way to remove the Token Generator option and a different approach that's altogether different, I'm open to that too.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.  It was in the models.py....

```
def get_available_methods():
    methods = [('generator', _('Token generator'))]
    methods.extend(get_available_phone_methods())
    methods.extend(get_available_yubikey_methods())
    return methods
```

I removed the ('generator', _('Token generator')) reference from inside the brackets ( list ) and it removed the Token Generator option.